# How can I add an image to my Run for a RichTextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote a small WPF app where I like to prepend text into a RichTextBox, so that the newest stuff is on top. I wrote this, and it works:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Prepends the text to the rich textbox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textoutput">The text representing the character information.</param>
    private void PrependSimpleText(string textoutput)
    {
        Run run = new Run(textoutput);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(run);

        if (this.RichTextBoxOutput.Document.Blocks.Count == 0)
        {
            this.RichTextBoxOutput.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        }
        else
        {
            this.RichTextBoxOutput.Document.Blocks.InsertBefore(this.RichTextBoxOutput.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock, paragraph);
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to make a new version of that function which can add small images as well. I'm at a loss though - is it possible to add images?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\SimpleImage.jpg"));
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = bi;
InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer(image);            
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(container); 
RichTextBoxOutput.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

The InlineUIContainer is the "magic" here... You can add any UIElement to it. If you want to add multiple items, use a panel to wrap the items (ie. StackPanel, etc)

Comment: Aha - I could not get my head around the bitmap -> image -> inlineuicontainer -> paragraph thing. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

RickTextbox.Document is a FlowDocument to which you can add almost anything that implements ContentElement. That includes Image, Label, StackPanel and all your other WPF favourites.

Check out the [FlowDocument Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but I've been playing around with it for a while and could not seem to get the right combination of objects to make it work.